# Oracle Object : How to show all the fields in select query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following Oracle Object :

```
CREATE TYPE person_typ AS OBJECT (
  Id NUMBER,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(20),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25));
```

And a table :

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  contact         person_typ,
  contact_date    DATE );
```

I would like to make a select query to show all the fields of the Person_Typ object  without specifiying their names.

When I do

```
select * from MyTable
```

The column contact is shown as **[unsupported data type]**, I have to use instead :

```
select T.contact.ID, T.contact.First_name, T.contact.last_name  from MyTable T
```

Is there another way to show the values of the object without specifying the column names ?

Thanks, 
Cheers,

Comment: Please do not use `*` except in exploratory interactive usage. Your queries should always explicitly list all columns so that later schema changes can easily/automatically find affected queries.

Comment: Thanks for the advance but this is not the question :)

Comment: The display depends on the SQL client you are using.

Comment: I'm using SQL developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use SQL Developer, but according to this article [Showing TYPE’d Column Values in SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/05/showing-typed-column-values-in-sql-developer/) you could use option:

Preferences / Database / Advanced / Display Struct Value in Grid

Also you can query `user_type_attr` (or `all_type_attr`) to obtain column names. Then copy/paste `select` part from output and run it or create view as proposed by @sep. Here is my test data and code block:

```
insert into mytable values (person_typ(1, 'Paulina', 'Thomson'), date '2017-12-17');
insert into mytable values (person_typ(7, 'Keanu', 'Stevens'), date '2017-12-28');

declare 
  v_sql varchar2(32000);
begin
  select listagg('T.CONTACT.'||attr_name||' '||attr_name, ', ') 
         within group (order by attr_no) 
    into v_sql
    from user_type_attrs 
    where type_name = 'PERSON_TYP';

  v_sql := 'SELECT '||v_sql||' FROM MYTABLE T';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
  execute immediate 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_CONTACTS AS '||v_sql;
end;

select * from vw_contacts;
```

Result:

```
    ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME
------ -------------------- -------------------------
     1 Paulina              Thomson
     7 Keanu                Stevens
```

Comment: Perfect ! Exacly what I need. Browsing the attributes of a type without knowing their names in advance using dynamic SQL. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I created a view with all the fields. In your case:

```
CREATE VIEW v_myTable AS 
   select T.contact.ID, T.contact.First_name, T.contact.last_name  
   from MyTable T
```

and use the view instead of the table

```
SELECT * from v_myTable
```

Comment: Actually, if I was able to execute a query like : select T.contact.ID, T.contact.First_name, T.contact.last_name  from MyTable T, I wouldn't create a view. The question is more about how to show the all the fields of an object in a query without knowing it' fields.